# How do I stop emails highlighting dates (with links to my calendar)?

Tags: ipad, email, calendar

On my iPad, how do I stop emails highlighting dates (with links to my calendar). I find this distracting.

Comment: Same in OSX and apps like Messages

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by replacing each character in the formatted date using the follow regexp:

```
(.{1})
```

and then replacing with

```
$1&zwnj;
```